# Converting HtmlDocument.DomDocument to string

Tags: c#, dom

How to convert HtmlDocument.DomDocument to string?

Answer (score 8):

This example is a bit convoluted, but, assuming you have a form called `Form1`, with a WebBrowser control called `webBrowser1`, the variable `content` will contain the markup that forms the document:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(@"http://www.robertwray.co.uk/");          
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var document = webBrowser1.Document;
    var documentAsIHtmlDocument3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)document.DomDocument;

    var content = documentAsIHtmlDocument3.documentElement.innerHTML;
}
```

The essential "guts" of extracting it from the `HtmlDocument.DomDocument` is in the `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` event handler.

*Note: `mshtml` is obtained by adding a COM reference to 'Microsoft HTML Object Library` (aka: mshtml.dll)*

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to use the `HtmlDocument` itself, rather than its `DomDocument` property:

```
string html = htmlDoc.Body.InnerHtml;
```

Or even simpler, if you have access to the `WebBrowser` containing the document:

```
string html = webBrowser.DocumentText;
```

Comment: actually i needed DomDocument because DocumentText doesn't change after the DOM is manipulated.any way thanks for the answer