# Cell Number Scraping from web

Tags: c#, regex

I'm pretty new in c#.net and I want to create a mobile number extractor from website

I want to do that if I have a website like `olx.com.pk` and I have extracted all the link from it and want to extract number from those link.

How can I do this, I've done link extraction very far want to know about mobile

here is a link extractor code of mine:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        wb.Url = new Uri(textBox1.Text);
        wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;
    }

    void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument code = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document;
        extract(code);
    }

    private void extract(HtmlDocument code)
    {

        HtmlElementCollection anchorList = code.GetElementsByTagName("a");

        foreach (var item in anchorList)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(((HtmlElement)item).GetAttribute("href"));
        }

    }
```

here is regular expression for Pakistani mobile number.

`^((\+92)|(0092))-{0,1}\d{3}-{0,1}\d{7}$|^\d{11}$|^\d{4}-\d{7}$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the link-collection part right, all you have to do now is open every single link and match [text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3640279/1149736) using [`Matches()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(\+92|0092)-?\d{3}-?\d{7}|\d{11}|\d{4}-\d{7}");

foreach(string link in listBox1.Items){
    // Load data to `HtmlDocument code`
    string text = ((mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)code.DomDocument).documentElement.innerHTML;

    foreach( Match match in re.Matches(text)){
        // do what you need
    }
}
```

And to prevent longer numbers from matching too you can use [negative lookahead/lookbehind expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#grouping_constructs):

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<!\d)((\+92|0092)-?\d{3}-?\d{7}|\d{11}|\d{4}-\d{7})(?!\d)");
```

Comment: 0345 2567504 this number ignored! please what to do now?

Comment: You've proposed regexp requiring number to be as one number (`03452567504`) or *dash-separated* (`0345-2567504`), if you want it to handle different format you have to add it, either by changing last portion of regex from `|\d{4}-\d{7}` to `|\d{4}[ -]\d{7}` or adding `|\d{4}\s+\d{7}` to the end of the regexp.

Comment: bro once again I'm disturbing you but this \d{11} describes the number can be 11 numeric characters but it's getting all numeric character that are in page with the lenght of 11 chars i want only 11 characters that starts with 03 and go afterwords to complete 11 chars!

Comment: @CodyMan ah, I forgot about that :), Added piece of code on that... Also with link to documentation