# C# - Get a render html page

Tags: javascript, c#, html

i am trying to get html string from my site as it presented in browser

firstly i tried to use web client

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var content = client.DownloadString("my_site_address");
}
```

but in my site i have some javascript code that change the view (and webClient does not run javascript)

so i use wpf WebBrowser and after nevigate to the desire site it show the page (as expected) but when i try to get the html string it show just like the webClient

```
        dynamic doc = MainBrowser.Document;
        var htmlText = doc.documentElement.InnerHtml;
```

this is how i get the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="conteiner">
        <div class="matrix">
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                // some script code
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="xxx"></script>
            <a href="Matrix/index.html">Matrix</a>
        </div>
        <div class="zoom">
            <a href="zoom/index.html">Zoom</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="test">
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                // some script code
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src"xxx2"></script>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is how i should get it after the javascript change it:

```
<html><head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
  <body>
  <div class="conteiner">
        <div class="matrix">
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="xxx"></script><iframe ></iframe><script ></script><div ><div ><iframe >

<html><head>
        <title></title>
</head>
        <body>
            <div >
            <ul><li><ol><li <a </a></li></ol></li></ul>        </div>

</body></html>

 </iframe></div></div></div>
            <a href="Matrix/index.html">Matrix </a>
        </div>
        <div class="zoom">
            <a href="zoom/index.html">Zoom</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="test">
            <script type="text/javascript"> 

</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="xxx2"></script><div ><div ><div ><iframe ></iframe></div></div></div>
        </div>

</body></html>
```

Please help :)

Comment: Can't do this with the tools you are using.

Comment: You probably need to do this on the client-side, not the server-side.

Comment: your best bet is to recreate the javascript functions in c# and process the html after you retrieve it.

Comment: You could try webkit.net http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: so which tools do i need?

Comment: The answer to this question implies you can do it with the WebBrowser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640236/converting-htmldocument-domdocument-to-string  You'd need to use the MSHTML interface to access the DomDocument.

Comment: Check my answer. I've already posted the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/index.html) framework from [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/). It offers different web driver implementations, like for Internet Explorer or Firefox.

Here is some sample code to request a web site with Internet Explorer, let it render and finally save the final HTML markup.

```
public class WebSiteHtmlLoader : IDisposable
{
    private readonly RemoteWebDriver _remoteWebDriver;

    public WebSiteHtmlLoader(RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver)
    {
        if (remoteWebDriver == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("remoteWebDriver");
        _remoteWebDriver = remoteWebDriver;
    }

    public string GetRenderedHtml(Uri webSiteUri)
    {
        if (webSiteUri == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("webSiteUri");
        _remoteWebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(webSiteUri);

        return _remoteWebDriver.PageSource;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_remoteWebDriver != null)
            {
                _remoteWebDriver.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (!args.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var pageUrl = args.First();
        var options = new InternetExplorerOptions
        {
            IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
            PageLoadStrategy = InternetExplorerPageLoadStrategy.Eager
        };

        using (var htmlLoader = new WebSiteHtmlLoader(new InternetExplorerDriver(options)))
        {
            var html = htmlLoader.GetRenderedHtml(new Uri(pageUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\htmlloadertext.html", html);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try to use the WebBrowser.DocumentText property. Like, add a hidden WebBrowser control to your application and call Navigate() function, then call the property to get the generated HTML
More info at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx